# Wanted: SQL query to count records meeting certain criteria & return info about highest count

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got a puzzle for you... I have database table that stores scores for a game.  It records the name of the player, the name of their computer opponent, and the final scores for each:

```
 player_name | bot_name | player_score | bot_score
---------------------------------------------------
  Alan         bot1          2            1
  Bill         bot1          3            0 
  Casey        bot2          5            0
  Alan         bot2          0            3
  Bill         bot3          1            2           
  Casey        bot3          4            0
  Alan         bot4          0            3
```

For each bot, the player with the largest margin of victory is the one with the highest (player_score - bot_score) value.  I want to write a SQL query that finds the player who has the most largest margins of victory.

Example: In the table above, Bill has the largest margin of victory over bot1, Casey has the largest margins of victory over bot2 and bot3, and no player has a largest margin of victory over bot4 since no player won against that bot.  So, Bill has one largest margin of victory, and Casey has two.  In this scenario, the query should return "Casey" and "2" since that's the player with the most largest margins of victory.

Is it possible to write a single SQL query to retrieve this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather complicated.  For each bot, you can the player (or players) with the largest margin by doing:

```
select bot_name, max(player_score - bot_score) as max_diff
from t
where player_score > bot_score
group by bot_name;
```

To get the players with the maximum score is a bit trickier:

```
select t.*
from t
where (t.player_score - t.bot_score) = 
       (select max(player_score - bot_score) as max_diff
        from t t2
        where t2.player_score > t2.bot_score and
              t2.bot_name = t.bot_name
       );
```

But, that is still not what you want.  You want the players with the largest such wins.  Here is how you get the list in order:

```
select t.player_name, count(*) as num_wins
from t
where (t.player_score - t.bot_score) = 
       (select max(player_score - bot_score) as max_diff
        from t t2
        where t2.player_score > t2.bot_score and
              t2.bot_name = t.bot_name
       )
group by t.player_name
order by num_wins desc;
```